# How to access to an element from an object retrieve from Parse.com?

Tags: php, parse-platform

Thank you for your time and please excuse for my english.

I have two classes in a proyect on Parse.com:

"_User" and "Sedes".

Inside "_User" there is one column (NombreSede_FK) wich points to a column inside "Sedes" (NombreSede).

When I ask for the content of an object in "_User" I get that the value of the column NombreSede_FK is an array (or some kind of object).

The problem is that I can´t access the values of that array.

Here is the info inside the array when a do **print_r($var->NombreSede_FK)**:

```
Parse\ParseObject Object
(
[serverData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[operationSet:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
    (
    )

[dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
    (
    )

[className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Sedes
[objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => JNMeQHySaD
[createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 
[updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 
[hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 
)
```

So, the value that I need to get access is:

[objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => **JNMeQHySaD**

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this work? `$var->NombreSede_FK->getObjectId();`

Comment: Yes!!!! Thanks a lot man! You are my new PHP God @Michas

Comment: One last thing. If I would like to retrive, instead of the string JNMeQHySaD (that is the pointer) the actual name of the object that its pointing, how can achive that? That objectId JNMeQHySaD is pointing to an object in a Class called "Sedes" and the column I want to look at is called "Nombre_Sede". So, it´s gonna be more readable to see, for example, "New York" insted of JNMeQHySaD. Thank again!!!!